# After first visit, auto populate a form with previous user input using PHP cookies?

Tags: php, html, forms, cookies

Basically I want to create a cookie in PHP that remembers what a user has entered into a form (that directs to a separate page), so that anytime they come back to the page, the form is already prepopulated with whatever information they put into it the first time around.

I've looked everywhere and can't really find a good answer for how to do this. This is how my code is configured right now (which isn't working).

PHP:

```
    $fname =  $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];

    setcookie( "fname", $fname, time() + 36000 );
    setcookie( "lname", $lname, time() + 36000 );
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="hidden.php">
<p>
    First Name: <input type="text" maxlength="40" name="fname" id="fname" value="
    <?php 
        if(isset($_COOKIE['fname']))
        {
            echo $_COOKIE['fname'];
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "";
        }
    ?>"/>
</p>
<p>
    Last Name: <input type="text" maxlength="40" name="lname" id="lname" value="
    <?php 
        if(isset($_COOKIE['lname']))
        {
            echo $_COOKIE['lname'];
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "";
        }
    ?>"/>
</p>
```

Any mind telling me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: the else case near `isset` is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You're close, however `$fname` in your HTML is empty (presuming you've submitted all relevant code). You need to either set `$fname` to the value of `$_COOKIE['fname']`, or just echo the cookie value directly. For instance:

```
echo $_COOKIE['fname']; // Be sure to sanitize this!
```

Comment: Hmmm okay. I edited both, and now it's working, but only for the first name field? I'll post my edited code so you can see if I messed up anything that I'm not catching for the last name field.

Comment: Check that your cookie isn't empty. I notice in your PHP you only set the cookie if both values are NULL. That seems incorrect; you probably mean != NULL.

Comment: Right, it's not. I've actually since edited the code and removed that completely, because I want the cookie to reset anytime the info is changed or updated.

Comment: Do a print_r or var_dump of $_COOKIE and ensure the data is set as you'd expect. I'd imagine that will shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Alright, I got it working for both fields. Now I'm noticing though that it only sticks after one page refresh? Have any idea what that could be about?

Comment: Without looking at your code in it's entirety, I couldn't say. I'd guess you're setting the cookie after you are echoing it or something.